# Is the phrase "You can cancel a subscription anytime" correct?

Tags: grammar, articles, american-english, indefinite-article

One native speaker said that it is a mistake to use the indefinite article in the phrase "You can cancel a subscription anytime". I want to ask native speakers if it's true, and if yes — what rule states this?

She said:

1. "You can cancel subscription anytime" — not a mistake, but could be better
2. "You can cancel a subscription anytime" — incorrect!
3. "You can cancel the subscription anytime" — this one is ok
4. "You can cancel your subscription anytime" — ok as well
5. "Subscription can be canceled at any time" — the best option

So, my questions are why #1 is correct (zero article?) and why #2 was considered as a wrong variant.

Comment: I would advise you not to trust this particular "native speaker" in the future (when it comes to language instruction). These assertions are not correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a mistake to say "a subscription" but it is not normally what you mean.

The first example looks wrong to me.  The word "subscription" should be used a countable noun, and so you need some article or determiner.

The second is correct. If a person had multiple subscriptions and the meaning was "you can cancel one of them".  However this is unlikely. Normally you would only have a single subscription, but if you had many, you could say "You can cancel [your] subscriptions at any time."

The third and fourth are correct.

The fifth is odd, again you seem to be treating "subscription" as an abstract non-count noun. It would be possible to say "Subscriptions can be cancelled..." but there is no real benefit in using the passive here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, James! Any idea why she said that #2 is incorrect?

Comment: Because it is not normally what you would mean or say.  You normally mean to say "your subscription" or "the subscription". So "You can cancel a subscription" would be rather odd.

Comment: Ok, but why she said that #1 is correct?

Comment: @JamesK We can usually leave out articles in headlines, so doesn't it apply to form fields, buttons and brief messages produced by a program?

Comment: no idea,  why don't you ask her. Did you miss out a plural?

Comment: No, I didn't miss a plural. I can't ask her directly, but I'll ask my friend to ask her.